# Open struct in matlab with varying struct name

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a series of structs in different files that i want to read in to my program. When the file is loaded i want to open and reach specific values in the struct with the following code.

```
structname_string='M1' 

I=structname.Y(5).Data
```

However it doesn't see structname as a variable containing M1. It tries to open a struct called "structname", which does not exist.

I tried simple and direct approaches such as genvarname() but didn't work either. I did not find any similar questions asked here with any simple answer.

Br

Comment: Using dynamic variable names is a bad idea. But if you need to do that, use `eval` (which is also not recommended). It would be something as follows, if I understand your question correctly: `structname = 'M1'; eval(['I=' structname '.Y(5).Data'])`

Comment: [getField](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getfield.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, I think that the function you want is [isfield()](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfield.html), where you can query whether the string name for a field within the structure exists.

If `isfield()` returns true, then you can perform the structure read knowing that the field exists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `struct`s are stored in `.mat` files, what you can do is this:

```
fs = load(filename);
I = fs.(structname_string).Y(5).Data;
```

`fs` contains all variables stored in `filename`, and is itself a `struct` whose fields can be accessed dynamically.

Comment: Thank you! this worked fine